# Should we use Data Transfer Object (DTO) from BLL project as model in view in Web project to display data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Should we use Data Transfer Object (DTO) from BLL project as model in view in Web project to display data or we should always create ViewModel? What is the best approach?**

For example I have in BLL project DTO class:

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

In Web project in controller action I call method from BLL project which returns me data type of EmployeeDTO. Then I use EmployeeDTO as model in view.

```
// in controller:
public ActionResult Employee(int id)
{
    EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = BLL.BusinessLogic.GetEmployee(id);

    return View(employeeDTO);
}

// in view:
@model BLL.DTO.EmployeeDTO

<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
    </dd>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Age)
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Is it correct or maybe I should create ViewModel, map data from DTO to ViewModel and use ViewModel in view? But then ViewModel will be the same like DTO.

```
// ViewModel the same like DTO
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you dont understand the answer feel free to add a comment or did it answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You probably would not need to create a view model for those example classes. These would work just fine without view model mappings. But if those are only examples and you have a bigger domain model, then it depends on a number of questions:

1. Is the domain model very complex, are there deep inheritance trees?
2. Do you want to add view specific information to the classes?

If those two are answered positively then it would probably be useful to create a view model mapping. There are some circumstances where certain mechanisms tend to get a bit complicated especially when serializing to and from JSON. A very deep domain class tree can get you into trouble here.

I would always advise to use a dedicated view model and map the domain model with `AutoMapper`, since its use is very easy and efficient and that way you are also able to extend the view model classes with view specific information, that has no place in the domain model. Which becomes especially interesting when the domain model is used in other applications or layers and should not be cluttered with view data.